# jQuery Sort time in 'hh min' mode

Tags: jquery, sorting, time

I have a table with a row that has the time in 'hh min' format. Im trying to sort the row converting it into minutes with the following jquery formula:

```
RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(a, b) {
            var ahour = (a.split(' ')[0].match(/\d+/))*60+(a.split(' ')[1].match(/\d+/));
            var bhour = (b.split(' ')[0].match(/\d+/))*60+(b.split(' ')[1].match(/\d+/));
   return $(ahour).replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '').localeCompare($(bhour).replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''))
})
```

But the console gives me the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: a.split is not a function"

How do I split the variable in order to sort it?

Complete code for your reference:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#SortBy").on('change', function() {

    var Rows = $('.CompTable tr');
    var RowtoSort = $(".CompTable tr." + $(this).find("option:selected").text());

    RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(a, b) {
      var ahour = (a.split(' ')[0].match(/\d+/)) * 60 + (a.split(' ')[1].match(/\d+/));
      var bhour = (b.split(' ')[0].match(/\d+/)) * 60 + (b.split(' ')[1].match(/\d+/));
      return $(ahour).replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '').localeCompare($(bhour).replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''))

    }).each(function(new_Index) {
      var original_Index = $(this).index();
      Rows.each(function() {
        var td = $(this).find('td, th');
        if (original_Index !== new_Index)
          td.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(td.eq(new_Index));
      });
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.CompTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Sort by:
<select id="SortBy">
  <option></option>
  <option>Time</option>
</select>

<table class="CompTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Samsung</th>
      <th>LG</th>
      <th>Apple</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Time">
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>2h 32min</td>
      <td>4h 57min</td>
      <td>3h 33min</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need `split`, `match` or `replace`. Just [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `numeric` option does the job

```
"2".localeCompare("10", undefined, {numeric: true}); // -1
```

```js
$("#SortBy").on('change', function() {

  var Rows = $('.CompTable tr');
  var RowtoSort = $(".CompTable tr." + $(this).find("option:selected").text());

  RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text(), undefined, {numeric: true})
  }).each(function(new_Index) {
    var original_Index = $(this).index();
    Rows.each(function() {
      var td = $(this).find('td, th');
      if (original_Index !== new_Index)
        td.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(td.eq(new_Index));
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.CompTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Sort by:
<select id="SortBy">
  <option></option>
  <option>Time</option>
</select>

<table class="CompTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Samsung</th>
      <th>LG</th>
      <th>Apple</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Time">
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>2h 10min</td>
      <td>2h 1min</td>
      <td>3h 33min</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Problems in your approach**

1. `a.split(' ')` - `a` is a HTMLElement not string
2. `a.split(' ')[0]` - may returns undefined
3. `a.split(' ')[0].match` - undefined.match wont works
4. `$(ahour)` - ahour is a Number. why $() here?
5. `$(ahour).replace` - $(ahour) returns jquery object, why replace?
6. `localeCompare` - comparing jquery object wrapped numbers with regex replace

```
    RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(a, b) {
        a = $(a).text();
        b = $(b).text();
        var a0 = a.split(' ')[0] || '';
        var a1 = a.split(' ')[1] || '';
        var b0 = b.split(' ')[0] || '';
        var b1 = b.split(' ')[1] || '';
        var ahour = (a0.match(/\d+/)) * 60 + (a1.match(/\d+/));
        var bhour = (b0.match(/\d+/)) * 60 + (b1.match(/\d+/));
        return ahour - bhour
      })
```

Comment: Hi @User863! Thanks, I guess in this case, converting it into numeric strings and comparing them does the job as well!! :)               However, please do tell me where was I going wrong with my approach of converting the time into minutes and comparing them, for my own understanding and future reference!!

Comment: @MithunUchil Problems in your approach added

Comment: @MithunUchil FYI. Inverting the table along with the [datatables](https://datatables.net) would be a better UX.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the jquery objects to strings:

```
RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(ao, bo) {
            a = ao.text();
            b = bo.text();
            var ahour = (a.split(' ')[0].match(/\d+/))*60+(a.split(' ')[1].match(/\d+/));
            var bhour = (b.split(' ')[0].match(/\d+/))*60+(b.split(' ')[1].match(/\d+/));
   return $(ahour).replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '').localeCompare($(bhour).replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''))
})
```

Comment: Hi @The Molecule ! I tried your edit, but it's still throwing the error "ao.text() is not a function". I also tried changing it to ````a = $(ao).text()```` but this also gives me an error "$(...).replace is not a function". :(